# Is my monero core wallet seed password compatible when using android monerujo app?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, android-wallet, monerujo

Can I use my same seed phrase from monero core on the monerujo app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can recover a wallet from its mnemonic seed in monerujo. It's detailed in the [FAQ](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/v1.2.1/doc/FAQ.md) in the list of features:

> Recover wallets from mnemonic seed or from keys